# Is there a way to "refresh" a request?

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I'm trying to download files from a website using python requests module and beautifulsoup4 but the problem is that you have to wait for 5 seconds before the download button appears.

I tried using `requests.get('URL')` to get the page and then parse it with `beautifulsoup4` to get the download link but the problem is that you have to wait 5 seconds (if you were to open it with an actual browser) in order for the button to appear so when I pass the URL to `requests.get()` the initial response object doesn't have the button element I searched a lot on google but couldn't find any results that helped me.

Is there a way to "refresh" the response object? or "wait"? that is to update it's contents after five seconds as if it were opened with a browser?

I don't think this is possible with the requests module. What should I do?

I'm running Windows10 64x

I'm new so sorry if the formatting is bad. :(

Comment: You'll have to figure out what the mechanism is that makes the download button appear. It's possible it's only JavaScript on the client side, in which case the actual download URL is probably available in the page's source code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does exist in the source code but I can't parse it with an html parser like beautifulsoup4 I'll try selenium as people suggested (When I look at the html code while the page is opened the button element appears out of no where after 5 seconds so it is probably javascript)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is stateless, every new request goes as a different request to the earlier one. We typically imeplement states in cookies, browser stoarges and so on. Being a plain HTTP client, there is no way for `requests` to *refresh* a request, and the next request will be a compleletly new request.

What you're looking for is some client that understands JavaScript and can handle page update automatically. I suggest you to look at `selenium` which can do browser automation.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
   driver.quit()
```